# Windows XP: Zero size files and folders but explorer still sees the files

Tags: windows, windows-xp, gnuwin32

I used a series of GNU find.exe commands to move media files to the current folder. Explorer show that the folders and files still exist in their original location but properties show zero size and files. I performed a chkdisk and that didnt help. Any ideas how to recover these files?

Here are the commands from my bat file.

```
find.exe . -mindepth 1 -name "*.mkv" -type d -exec mv {} {}.tmp ;
find.exe . -mindepth 2 -type f -exec mv {} . ;
find.exe . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec rmdir {} ;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

The path was too long so I renamed the folder.